# Простейшая авторизация в Golang

Tags: golang

День добрый! Необходимо написать авторизацию на Go. Использую Revel. Смотрел примеры работы с сессиями, но у самого они магическим образом не работают. Авторизация происходит на одной странице, а сам проект на другой. Необходимо запретить переход на страницу проекта (да и выполнение запросов через адресную строку), если пользователь не авторизован. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В Revel существуют Filters по типу Middleware в Nodejs, PHP и так далее.
Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://revel.github.io/manual/filters.html). Логику фильтра можете написать самостоятельно, я приведу простейший пример

Вам необходимо прежде всего создать новый фильтр и затем подключить его в `init()` в файле `YourppName/app/init.go`

```
var AuthFilter = func(c *revel.Controller, fc []revel.Filter) {

   // Список URL не попадающих под фильтр авторизации
   allowedPathList := []string{"public", "auth"}
   path := strings.Split(c.Request.URL.Path, "/")

   timestamp := time.Now()

   // Просмотр всех входящих запросов
   fmt.Println("<", c.Request.Method, ">", c.Request.URL.Path,
       timestamp.Hour(), ":", timestamp.Minute(), ":", timestamp.Second(), "/", timestamp.Nanosecond())

   allowed := false
   for _, allowedPath := range allowedPathList {
       if path[1] == allowedPath {
           allowed = true
       }
   }

   if !allowed && c.Request.Method != "POST" {
       fmt.Println("Auth Filter Trap")

       tokenCookie, err := c.Request.Cookie("token")
       if err != nil {
           // Это произойдет, если очистили куки, либо пользователь пришел на сайт впервые.
           fmt.Println("Cannot get cookie")

           initCookie := http.Cookie{
               Name:   "token",
               Value:  "",
               Domain: "localhost:9000", // домен, который будет тянуть этот кук
           }
           c.SetCookie(&initCookie)
           return
       }

       token := tokenCookie.GetValue()
       ... тут добавляем объект, который будет осуществлять проверку ...

       if !auth.CheckToken(token) {
           fmt.Println("Bad token")
           c.Request.URL.Path = "/auth_redirect"
       } else {
           fmt.Println("Allowed")
       }
   }
   fc[0](c, fc[1:]) // Execute the next filter stage.
}
```

После создания фильтра, необходимо его добавить как было указано выше

```
func init() {
    // Filters is the default set of global filters.
    revel.Filters = []revel.Filter{
        revel.PanicFilter, // Recover from panics and display an error page instead.
        AuthFilter, // как вы видите, лучше запихать фильтр авторизации повыше (до роутинга)
        revel.RouterFilter,            // Use the routing table to select the right Action
    ... Другие фильтры (стандартные фильтры ревел) ...

    }
}
```